Checker map size changes after packing uv
I am using TexTools and UV Packer AddOn on blender, I used TexTools to set a resolution to the checker map i have applied on the components of the object. but as soon as I use UV Packer and click on pack the size of checkers in the object changes to big one. It happens even if I use the blender default pack option.



I assume it's packing all the selected objects in a single UV map so each individual object has less texture space. Select only one object before unpacking

The appearance of the textures on the mesh is dependent on the size and orientation of the UVs. When you use packing tools these try to optimize the usage of the available space. In order to use as much space as possible, the tools have to scale and rotate UVs and therefore the appearance of course changes with the change of the UVs. If you would show the UVs before using the packing tools I guess there will be obvious differences (if not I would wonder what the tool actually does).

If I try to use fixed scale then the UVs goes outside the uv map in the uv editng space. I wonder if the uv map's resolution is the issue. If I try to fit everything in the map then the same checkered squares density get reduced.

In your first screenshot using Tex Tools, you have the UV space size set to  4096 x 4096 pixels but in your second screenshot the UV space is set to only 512 x 512 pixels. Try using  the same size UV space when using  UV-Packer as when using Tex Tools then perhaps you will notice less difference in checker square size on the models.

I tried using the same pixels but still the same result

Then my guess is that each object in your Scope Low collection has been first UV unwrapped individually into a UV space and now when they are all selected together, many of these objects UV's islands are stacked above other UV islands. When using the UV-Packer tool all the UV islands will occupy their own uv space (with a margin between them) and so need to be resized smaller to fit into the same UV space.
